# FormControl boolean without default value in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I'm using reactive forms in angular 2 (4.1.2)

I have a boolean property which I don't want to have a default value but it should be required.

This is how I create my form:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        payedOvertime: [false, Validators.required],
    });
}
```

And my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Payed overtime</label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="payedOvertime" formControlName="payedOvertime" [value]="true" />Yes
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="payedOvertime" formControlName="payedOvertime" [value]="false" />No
    </label>
</div>
```

The problem is that while this works the radiobutton is preselected but I do not want that, rather it should have to be selected by clicking at one of the radio-buttons. If neither of the radiobuttons are clicked I want the form to be invalid.

Comment: If it is a true boolean then why not use a simple checkbox? Is it a requirement that it be a radio button?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `payedOvertime: [false, Validators.required]` to `payedOvertime: [null, Validators.required]`.

Given that you set it to `false`, it matches the value of `No` radio button in the template and it selects it by default (rightly so). Setting it to `null` will prevent Angular from matching the value with any of those declared in the template and thus non of those radio buttons will be selected.

Answer (score 12):

Only change `Validators.required` to `Validators.requiredTrue`,
Something like:

`payedOvertime: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]`